# What happens if you need to play Missile Envy, but cannot due to Red Scare/Purge + Quagmire/Bear Trap?

Tags: twilight-struggle

Say `Quagmire`/`Bear Trap` as well as `Red Scare/Purge` are currently in effect. Opponent plays `Missile Envy`. Now I need to play `Missile Envy` on my turn, but I can't discard it to Quagmire/Bear Trap because it's 1-op now and those cards require 2 ops. What happens now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You discard different 2+ops cards until out of Q/BT, then play Missile envy.

This is a bizarre edge case. You can't play Missile Envy, thus you must play a different (2+ops) card. You must play the Missile Envy at the first AR after the Q/BT ends unless your hand is full of scoring cards.  If your hand is full of scoring cards then you can play the scoring cards and play the Missile Envy at AR1 of the next round.

Sources:

1. [Official FAQ](https://www.gmtgames.com/nnts/FAQv5.pdf):

> Q. How does one deal with a Missile Envy placed in one’s hand when
> under the effect of a Bear Trap or Quagmire? A. A player under Bear
> trap/Quagmire who has had Missile Envy played against him MUST use it
> as the next discard if its value has not been degraded by Red
> Scare/Purge.

2. [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/twilightstruggle/comments/bbpgxw/is_it_possible_to_trap_your_opponent_in_a)

> This is an exception to being forced to play missile envy on your next AR.

3. [BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1550581/combo-red-scarepurge-bear-trap-missile-envy)

> You must play Missile Envy at the very next possible AR, if it doesn't force you to lose the game. So, if you have nothing but scoring cards and ME by the time you exit Quagmire, you play the scoring cards (you can't be forced to hold them). If Quagmire/BT lasts across a turn boundary, you must use ME on the first AR (not headline) as a discard to Q/BT.

> (And, of course, if Terrorism/5YP/Ask Not/Grain Sales/etc causes ME to leave your hand, you clearly aren't forced to play it either).

4. [twilightstrategy:Missile Envy](https://twilightstrategy.com/2012/10/08/missile-envy/)

Wrong answer in the commnets, then `ddddddd` makes the correction:

> ... play a different card. I’m pretty sure we based this on something we read online somewhere.